# jQuery/Twitter API - Latest Tweet Question

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm using the following code to call the latest tweet on to my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=?', function(data) {
             $('#tweet').html(data[0].text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In to the DIV:

```
<div id="tweet"></div>
```

I'm just wondering what I need to add to display the date of the last tweet and display it in a "Posted X day(s) ago" format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) is the often go-to for this, with that you just need to use the `created_at` property of the tweet, for example:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=?', function(data) {
    $('#tweet').html(data[0].text + " - " + $.timeago(data[0].created_at));
  });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BVDVH/).

Comment: Perfect, what would I add to display the date in a div id of date?

Comment: @Vince - Like this: `$('#tweet').text(data[0].text); $('#date').text($.timeago(data[0].created_at));`

Comment: Any ideas on the error Chrome is throwing up since using the code? - "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json."

Comment: @Vince - that's twitter not setting the response headers completely correctly...it won't cause issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer by using JS to generate the tweet, but if you using server side script by get the XML of your latest tweet from twitter atom feed like `http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:'.$username.'&rpp='.$items`, from there by any XML parser you can read the time info for each tweet, and by creating some function you can process the data and display the tweet with a "Posted X day(s) ago".